# How do i crawl images from a website of infinite scrolling where the api is hidden and i cant get it from by using Inspect Element->Network

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl a webpage having infinite scrolling.So i could get get only images until first load and cant get them again. I even tried to find the ajax application call made for loading the images from Inspect Element-> Network. But found that its not making any ajax call,but the images are still loading.

Is there a way to hide the get requests made to get those images?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and extract the DOM nodes in there.
If you want, you can either use the standard DOM API or even jQuery.

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.sample.com', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log($(".yourimgclass"))
    });
    phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

Of course, you can tell PhantomJS, [to scroll down](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/scroll-position.html).